# Uploaded file not being saved to directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to upload a file using devexpress save as function which works exact same as the standard asp.net uploader but i am getting the following error

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Projects\fhs\fhs\Uploads\documents\VX00150\Barry Allen\Aperture - Signature Template.docx'.

UploadDirectory refers to a virutal directory setup in the web config  which im getting via the property.

```
 string UploadDirectory = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["uploadDirectory"].ToString();
```

Which contains the directory

```
<add key="uploadDirectory" value="~\Uploads\" />
```

But for the live of me I cannot see why the file is not saving to the server

```
protected void UploadControl_FileUploadComplete(object sender, FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e)
{


        UploadControl.Enabled = false;

          string id = Request.QueryString["Case"];
        if (id != null)
        {
            CaseId = Guid.Parse(id);
            OpenCase = _dal.GetCaseById(Guid.Parse(id));
        }
        string PersonId = Session["CurrentPersonalMainID"].ToString();
        Personal = _dal.GetPersonalByPersonalId(new Guid(PersonId));

        e.CallbackData = SavePostedFile(e.UploadedFile, OpenCase.CaseReference, Personal.firstName, Personal.lastName);

}
```

The below saved postedfile is called from above

```
public  string SavePostedFile(UploadedFile uploadedFile,string IVACaseRef, string firstName ,string lastName)
    {
        try
        {
if (!uploadedFile.IsValid)
            return string.Empty;
        string fileName = uploadedFile.FileName;

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(uploadedFile.FileName);

        string fullFileName = CombinePath(fileName);
        string docsPath = UploadDirectory +  @"documents\" + IVACaseRef + @"\" + firstName + " " +
                          lastName + @"\";
        string resFileName =docsPath + fileInfo.Name;
        bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(resFileName);

        if (!exists)
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(docsPath);

        uploadedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(resFileName), true);
        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
        attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(resFileName.ToString());

        // we need to reget this as issue with postback and the fileuplaod
        FormsIdentity _identity = (FormsIdentity)Context.User.Identity;
        _identity = (FormsIdentity)Context.User.Identity;




        return fileName;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)

    {
        string inner = string.Empty;
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            inner = ex.InnerException.ToString();
        }
        //     logger.Error("Error in GetNotificationById function aperturenetdal " + ex.ToString() + " " + inner);
        return "";
```

Comment: Maybe it's because of this: `\fhs\fhs`

Comment: @Hackerman no its not that the directory is like that im afraid

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that a lot of file manipulation methods and classes differ in how they handle spaces, sometimes in ways that are not well documented. For example, I've seen situations where testing for the existence of a file with a space in the filename succeeds but opening it does not.

It's just a hunch, but it seems likely.